# Im trying to send an automated email to users with current AD details using powershel ISE to grab AD details..But Ive never done this before

Tags: powershell, active-directory, azure-active-directory, powershell-4.0, activedirectorymembership

[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PRYY.png) 
I've never done this before but my boss gave me a hint how to go about this..but im still confused..can anyone help me out

```
enter code here$a = get-aduser -filter * -SearchBase 'OU=_Users,OU=Head Office,OU=1_A,OU=1_Oceania,OU=L,DC=l,DC=global' -SearchScope OneLevel -Properties employeeId,pager | Select name,EMPLOYEEid,PAGER | Where-Object -Property EmployeeId -EQ $null| Out-GridView


FOREACH ($B IN $A) {if (($B.pager-ne $null) -AND ($B.EmployeeID -eq $null)) {

$emp_Email = ''
$emp_Name = ''
$emp_Job = ''
$emp_Company = ''
$emp_Mobile = ''
$emp_DirectPhone= ''
$emp_empyloeeID = ''
$emp_mainnumber= ''
$emp_url=''
$emp_from=''

Hi <<UserName>>,
On the Jan 20th a new email sign software will be installed. This will standardize all email signs across all devices. Please check the below to ensure the details are correct. If there is missing data please reply to this email to have this addressed:
Name: <<Name>>
EmployeeId : <<EmpId>>
Job Title: <<Position>>
Company: <<Company>>
Mobile : <<Mobile>>
Direct Land Line: <<Direct>>
Main Number: <<Telephone>>
URL: <<URL>>
Please note that if some of the fields provided are empty do not panic the fields will be filled in.
}
}
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots - instead, post your code _as plain text_. We can help you after the fact if you're having trouble formatting it correctly, just paste it in at the bottom [of your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70509063/edit) :)

Comment: Sorry Mathias ill do that

Comment: Do you want to send the mails automatically from within powershell? There is this nice little cmdlet named `Send-MailMessage`. Microsoft doesn't recommend to use it anymore but hasn't come up with a proper alternative yet... Might not work if you use Exhange Online because of the enhanced Login...

Comment: @T-Me Unfortunately yes we do use exchange but I was intrsucted to just write up a general message and pull the relvent fields to the email that was going to be sent to each user..the thing is i havent used powershell before and i dont know if im going about this the right way to be honest havent coded in awhile either.

Comment: Use `@"` one line above your text an `"@` one below. You can just use the variables in the text: `" this is a string with a $variable"`

Comment: @T-Me right before the Hi <<username>> ?

Comment: @64CLAN jep. And `<<username>>` can be replaced with a variable that containts the username `Hi $Username`

Comment: You don't have to check for `$B.EmployeeID -eq $null` in the `if`, because you have filtered the users already on that in the `Where-Object` clause. Is it your intention to only search for users that have a pager but no employeeId? Which user attribute do you mean with _Direct Land Line_

Comment: @Theo so the pager field was used to store the employee id originally because the the emplyeeid in the users attributes wasnt filled in so its redundent now ive just recently moved all the information over to the right field..sorry haha

Comment: @theo the direct line is the home number in the telephone field in active directory

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the properties to use for the labels you give them in your code, but you could build on this.
It uses [Here-Strings](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-use-here-strings-with-powershell/), [ConvertTo-Html](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-html) and [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting)

```
# create a nice CSS style to format the table using a Here-String
$style = @'
<style>
    body {font-family: Calibri, Tahoma, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: black;}
    table {border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-collapse: collapse;}
    td {border-width: 1px; padding: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: black;}
</style>
'@

# the text to start the email with. This has one placeholder {0} that will be filled in with the user's first name in the loop
$preText = @'
Hi {0},<br /><br />
On the Jan 20th a new email sign software will be installed. This will standardize all email signs across all devices.<br />
Please check the below to ensure the details are correct. If there is missing data please reply to this email to have this addressed:
'@

# the static text to end the email with
$postText = '<br />Please note that if some of the fields provided are empty do not panic the fields will be filled in.'

# Get-ADUser already returns objects with these properties:
# DistinguishedName, Enabled, GivenName, Name, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, SamAccountName, SID, Surname, UserPrincipalName
# anything else you need to ask through the Properties parameter
$props = 'EmployeeID', 'pager', 'Company', 'MobilePhone', 'OfficePhone', 'HomePhone', 'HomePage', 'Title', 'EmailAddress'
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=_Users,OU=Head Office,OU=1_A,OU=1_Oceania,OU=L,DC=l,DC=global' -SearchScope OneLevel -Properties $props | 
         Where-Object {[string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.EmployeeId) -and ($null -ne $_.pager)}

foreach ($user in $users) {
    # fill in the '{0}' placeholder for the leading text with the users first name
    $leaderText = $preText -f $user.GivenName
    # create a sub selection of the properties needed in the email
    $properties = $user | Select-Object Name, EmployeeId,
                                        @{Name = 'Job Title'; Expression = {$_.Title}},
                                        Company,
                                        @{Name = 'Mobile'; Expression = {$_.MobilePhone}},
                                        @{Name = 'Direct Land Line'; Expression = {$_.HomePhone}},
                                        @{Name = 'Main Number'; Expression = {$_.OfficePhone}},
                                        @{Name = 'URL'; Expression = {$_.HomePage}}

    # or if you prefer this syntax:
    # $properties = [PsCustomObject]@{
    #     'Name'             = $user.Name
    #     'EmployeeId'       = $user.EmployeeId
    #     'Job Title'        = $user.Title
    #     'Company'          = $user.Company
    #     'Mobile'           = $user.MobilePhone
    #     'Direct Land Line' = $user.HomePhone
    #     'Main Number'      = $user.OfficePhone
    #     'URL'              = $user.HomePage
    # }

    # create the email body using the style above for the table
    $body = $properties | ConvertTo-Html -Head $style -PreContent $leaderText -PostContent $postText -As List

    # use Splatting on cmdlets that take a lot of parameters:
    $mailParams = @{
        From       = 'you@yourcompany.com'
        To         = $user.EmailAddress
        Subject    = 'New email sign-in software'
        Body       = $body -join "`r`n"
        BodyAsHtml = $true
        Priority   = 'High'
        SmtpServer = 'smtpmail.yourcompany.com'
        Port       = 587
        # more parameters go here
    }
    # send the email
    Send-MailMessage @mailParams
}
```

Of course, try this out on a dummy user first and make sure the email is sent to yourself to test the result.

Comment: Leo you bloody legend ill give this a go